# Unable to find a matching set of capabilities - geckodriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to add firefox profile and capabilities but getting exception while creating new firefox instance.
I know the new selenium versions uses gecko driver as firefox driver with firefox version >47.0. 
But does the driver support firefox profile?
You can find used capabilities, properties and stacktrace below.
Selenium Version: 3.4.0.
FireFox Version: >47.0.

**Set Capabilities:**

```
case FIREFOX:
        FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
        fp.setPreference("browser.download.dir", 
        System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\resources\\downloads");
        fp.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        fp.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);

        webCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        webCapabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fp);
```

**Driver Creation:**

```
case FIREFOX:
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//resources//drivers//geckodriver.exe");
            return new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

**Stack Trace**

```
> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching 
set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'NAEL', ip: '10.0.0.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 
'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: Driver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
0:           0x4bb74f - <no info>
1:           0x4bbea9 - <no info>
2:           0x43df94 - <no info>
3:           0x447acf - <no info>
4:           0x4203e1 - <no info>
5:           0x407dc7 - <no info>
6:           0x6d95b9 - <no info>
7:           0x4173a7 - <no info>
8:           0x6d38b3 - <no info>
9:     0x7ffe20e72774 - BaseThreadInitThunk
at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:69)
at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

Comment: What is your exact business requirement? You seem to be trying to use `FirefoxProfile` Class as well as `DesiredCapabilities` Class. Can you narrow down your question to your exact requirement?

Comment: @DebanjanB - Why is using a `FirefoxProfile` and a `DesiredCapabilities` an incorrect combination to work with ? It is a perfectly valid combination.

Comment: @Nael - What is the geckodriver version you are working with ? I tried using `Firefox 55.0.2 (64-bit)` on `Mac OS (Sierra)` with `geckodriver 0.18.0` and it seems to work fine. I would suggest that you please try once again with the latest FF version and latest geckodriver.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan At no point in my comment I have mentioned using a `FirefoxProfile` and a `DesiredCapabilities` an incorrect combination. I did add a **trying to use** clause. If you read my comment once again, I simply asked for a clarification. Let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan 
I'm using the last driver version and FF version 47.2 will try the last version.

Comment: @DebanjanB 
The most important requirement is to download files on workspace directory.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan 
Yes I know!
I upgraded selenium version this week and I have above problem with FF.

Comment: @NaelAbdeljawad Your question header and description no where mentions about `The most important requirement is to download files on workspace directory` as per your comment. Update the question as per your business case for further analysis.

Comment: @NaelAbdeljawad - You would need to perhaps move to using the latest FF version as well. The latest geckodriver version usually goes with the latest nightly build of FF.

Comment: Thanks everyone, works on the last FF and geckodriver versions!